# How to run a script that has src attribute using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form on a page "page1.php", like this:

```
<form id = "form1" action = "page2.php">
</form>
```

After executing an Ajax function, I add the following script into this form with .append():

```
<script id='mp_script'  src="https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
data-preference-id="9999999">
</script>
```

But this script does not run, how do I run it after adding it with Ajax?

Note: I cannot add this script other than with AJAX, as the "data-preference-id" attribute will change depending on what the user selects on the screen.

Comment: Why did you sure that your new script does not execute?

Comment: because when executing this script a button is included on the screen.

Comment: You could try to load another script file what can help you detect the script could be execute or not. ex: create a file called `test.js`, the file include something like `alert('Hello!');`, then `append` test.js script to your website by current way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `script` tag and then listen to the onload event to execute your logic.

```
const script = this.document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.src = url; // the script url like 
script.onload = () => {
  // your logic after script load
};

this.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on localhost

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.setAttribute('method', "post");
f.setAttribute('action', "the-url-to-post");
$('#div_mercadopago').append(f);

var s = document.createElement("script");
s.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js');
s.setAttribute('data-preference-id', Preference-ID**);

// add all elements to the form
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

**The Preference-ID that I presume you are getting from a webservice/ajax