# React, loading a script inside a form (mercadopago)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement some payment system ([MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/integration/#editor_1597368062)).

According to the doc, it's just pasting this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
    data-preference-id="589788715-2e52aeec-8275-487c-88ee-1a08cff37c08"
  ></script>
</form>
```

Pasting it in a pure html file works fine: a button appears and clicking it opens a modal to pay with a credit card as expected. However this doesn't work in React since it's dynamically loading a script. Hence, I tried using an effect hook to insert the `<script>` on load as such:

```js
const App = () => {
  const setMercadoPagoPreferences = async () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src =
      'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js';
    script.async = true; // commenting or uncommenting seems to have no effect
    script.setAttribute(
      'data-preference-id',
      '589788715-2e52aeec-8275-487c-88ee-1a08cff37c08'
    );
    document.getElementById('mercadoForm').appendChild(script);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMercadoPagoPreferences();
  }, []);

  return <form action='/procesar-pago' method='POST' id='mercadoForm' />;
};
```

This loads correctly the script, it seems, as a button to pay is appended to the page. Clicking it however opens a modal that says "oh no, something bad happened". This doesn't happen on my .html example above; so it must be because of how React is loading the script or something like that. It doesn't work on either the dev or the production build.

**Edit:** As suggested, I tried using refs instead of directly appending childs but this did not seem to have any impact, it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this framework but maybe thats the way: It looks like this guy has similar problem [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58143450/3765649).

I think there is problem because script does not load on time. So maybe lets try this:

```
script.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('mercadoForm').appendChild(script);
};
```

In addtion there is build in mechanism in react ref like [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of document.getElementById

Comment: The other guy did have a similar problem but it is different as his script was not loading at all, mine is (as a button appears), just that incorrectly (as clicking it pops up an error). Also, `script.onload` runs *after* the script has been appended to the document so that what you suggested doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your technique would've work if it weren't for `mercadolibre`.
Apparently, the use of the page you are trying to load is not allowed by `mercadolibre`. It's like you're trying to load `mercadolibre` inside an `Iframe` which they probably blocked using [CSP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors). Specifically they are setting the Content-Security-Policy tag to frame-ancestors 'self'. It's a security restriction standard that does not allow the use of pages from that domain within elements `Iframe`.

Comment: So is there no way to overcome it? Maybe some hacky thing.

Comment: There are some other ways to bypass the interpretation of the CSP headers, but I would suppose you're building a website for general use. I suggest you follow mercadolibre doc on how to integrate their plugin.

Comment: Their docs assume I am using a plain html file, but I want to integrate it to my SPA made in react. Their docs didn't mention any CSP headers either.